# Prove that $x^p\equiv 1$ (mod $p$) has only one solution.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, congruences

I know that said solution is $x\equiv 1$ (mod $p$). However, I'm having difficulty proving this result.

So far, I've tried $x^p\equiv 1$ (mod $p$) $ \Rightarrow $ $p\mid (x^p-1) \Rightarrow p\mid(x-1)(x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x + 1)$.

From here, it's clear that the objective is to somehow show that $p\mid(x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x + 1)$ also yields $x\equiv 1$ (mod $p$), but I've been unsuccessful in showing this after $(x^{p-1} + x^{p-2} + \cdots + x)\equiv-1$ (mod $p$).

Comment: Hint: Fermat's Little Theorem, are you familiar with this?

Comment: It doesn't have only one solution, unless you put some restriction on $x$ (and indeed $p$). You could claim that, for $p$ prime, if $m^p\equiv 1$ and $n^p \equiv 1$ then $m\equiv n \bmod p$

Comment: Hint: Use the fact that $x^p-1\equiv(x-1)^p\pmod p$.

Comment: Sorry, deleted my answer as I think it was very confused. Carry on.

Comment: Is it enough to say that by Fermat's Little Theorem, $x^p\equiv x$, and since $x^p\equiv 1$ (mod $p$), it must be that $x\equiv 1$ (mod $p$)?

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen could you please prove this fact ?

Comment: @Mostafadd Search for "Freshman's dream". It comes down to binomial formula, and the fact that all the binomial coefficients $\binom p k$, $0<k<p$, are divisible by $p$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(x-1)^p \equiv (x^p - 1) \mod p$  by binomial theorem. So, if $p$ divides $(x^p - 1)$, it certainly divides $(x-1)^p$. Therefore, by fermat's last theorem, $p$ divides $x-1$. Hence, you get the desired result.

Comment: Could you elaborate on why this guarantees the uniqueness of the solution?

Comment: $x^p \equiv x \mod p$ tells us that we only need to consider $0 \le x < p$ and the only value of $x$ in this range that is equivalent to $1$ is $1$ itself.

Comment: Thanks. Solution is clear now.

Comment: Could you please prove the first congruence                                         
$ (x-1)^p \equiv (x^p - 1) \mod p$

Answer (score 0):

Using Frobenius isomorphism you receive that $x^p-1 = (x-1)^p $. 
$\mathbb Z_p $ is a field, $\implies \mathbb Z_p [x]$ is a PID, therefore an integral domain, from which you can conclude that $(x-1)^p = 0 \iff (x-1)=0 \iff x = 1$

Comment: Hello, since you are new to Math.SE here is one tip to receiving upvotes on answers: Try to post the least mathematically demanding proofs for elementary questions such as this one. For much more advanced questions, it is often hard to judge to mathematical background of the asker so the shorter the better.